# Map.prototype.forEach does not exist Angular 6 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, tsconfig

I am attempting to take a C# Dictionary object from a Http response and cast it to a Map in JavaScript. I am unable to figure out why the heck I cannot use Map.prototype.forEach. It keeps telling me that it does not exist. According to the MDN for [Map.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) it was first introduced in ES2015. I included ES2015, ES2015.collection, and ES2015.iterable in the lib section of the tsconfig. I figured that would be enough but it does not seem to be working at all. Is there something that I am missing?

Below is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es2015",
      "es2015.collection",
      "es2015.iterable",
      "es2016",
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "checkJs": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
  }
}
```

Code I am attempting to use:

```
myMap: Map<number, Array<number>> = new Map<number, Array<number>>();
this.myMap.forEach((value: Array<number>) => {  /* ERROR HERE */
  console.log(value);
})
```

Here is the associated file for the Map interface Here is the associated code [Map interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts)

Here is a little info about the project:

Angular v6.0.4

Angular CLI v6.0.8

Typescript v2.7.2

Comment: And... didn't you forget to post the code ? Please see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: are you calling the prototype function? If so, try calling it on the iterable itself `arr.forEach(item)`

Comment: @DenysSéguret sorry I forgot to include the code. Edited for completeness.

Comment: Is new Map<number, Array<number>>() returns object, Could you please check?
Actually new always returns an object.

Comment: @AnkitPandey calling new Map<K, V> invokes the MapConstructor interface, which then uses the Map<K, V> interface and on this interface it shows the forEach method. Updated my answer to include the associated file on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stemmed from trying to take a C# Dictionary object in a Http response and type it as a Map. This just does not natively work. The response was returning a generic JavaScript Object of { K: number, V: number[] } even though I was typing it as a Map. Obviously an Object does not have the function forEach.